# Type of Underscore expression

Tags: typescript, underscore.js

Why this expression

```
_.chain(this.entityTypeConnections)
 .filter(function (con:app.domain.EntityTypeConnection) { return con.typeId == typeId; })
 .size()
 .value()
```

have a type `EntityTypeConnection[]`, but not the number?

I need to compare this expression with zero ( > 0 ) and get the error:

> error TS2365: Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'EntityTypeConnection[]' and 'number'

I am trying to check if there is an element in the collection with certain `typeId`.

Comment: Why are you calling `.value()` after `.size()`? Size will already give you the number - there is no need to call value...

Comment: I have tried without `size()`, but it have the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically I assume that you cannot use `size()` in a typed context. Checking the .d.ts files for underscore shows the its return type to be `_Chain<T>` which would be `_Chain<EntityTypeConnection[]` in your case - obviously this is wrong (run it in plain javascript and you will get your number).

### Alternatives

Get the value ("unchain") and just call `.length` on the array:

```
let size = _.chain(this.entityTypeConnections)
    .filter(function (con:app.domain.EntityTypeConnection) { return con.typeId == typeId; })
    .value()
    .length;
```

If you want to check the presence of an item with the given `typeId`, you can also just use:

```
let hasItem = !!_.findWhere(this.entityTypeConnections, {
    typeId: typeId
});
```